# SSRS 2016 upload rdl file error

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

When i try to upload rdl file implemented in VS 2015 version is giving error in ssrs 2016 SP1 version.

I get the following error.

> An error has occurred. Something went wrong. Please try again later.

Same error while creating a new data source/ paginated report from browser directly.

Previously we used to upload into SSRS 2012, was working fine.

Please suggest the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this issue? We're getting the same behaviour and this error in the web app log: OData exception occurred: System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices.SoapExceptionStrings.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed

Comment: Is this server using a custom authentication extension? Have you got any info in the web portal log file? e.g. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQL13\Reporting Services\LogFiles\Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost_05_04_2017_08_45_45.log. I'm speculating that this error occurs the first time the portal attempts to call the old wrapped ReportService2010 SOAP API and gets a connection or auth error.